# Interpreting order of magnitude correctly?

Tags: data-analysis, data-structure

Given this data table:

[image]

The lowest value: $79.3$

And the highest value: $1.27\times10^9$

If so, why would there be zero before the power? Such as $e+009$.

That notation was a bit confusing.

Comment: $009$ just means $9$. The zeros are likely there as a placeholder so that the text aligns nicely. If for example you wrote $9$ instead of $009$, and then farther up the scale you have $e+10$ or $e+100$ then the alignment of the numbers wouldn't look as nice.

Comment: Why not? This question appears to really be about some sort of computer program, and not about mathematics.